# How to describe S3 Bucket policy for preventing access error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I set `S3 Bucket Policy`I suffered `Access Denied`errors.

My json file is like below.
I couldn't figure out why such kind of errors occured.
If someone has some experience,please let me know.

```
 {
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
         "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
       "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
       "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::calendar-app/*"
       ]
     }
   ]
 }
```

[image]

Comment: You also have to include the prefix itself...  “arn:aws:s3:::calendar-app”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to save an S3 bucket policy that allows public (unauthenticated) access to objects under the `calendar-app` bucket. At the same time, your AWS account has [S3 Block Public Access](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-block-public-access-another-layer-of-protection-for-your-accounts-and-buckets/) configured, which is an account-level configuration preventing anyone from creating policies that allow public access.

If you genuinely need to support public access to this bucket then you will need to disable S3 Block Public Access. Otherwise write an S3 bucket policy that does not allow public access.